# How to popup 'Edit' window instead of load a 'Edit' page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently implementing the '**Edit**' feature of **CRUD** functionalities. I have a link which will call the '**edit**' function in CarsController. The link in view is:

```
%td
  =link_to(t("car.edit"), edit_car_path(car))
```

When user click the link, it goes to the '**Edit**' view page (edit.html.haml):

```
=form_for(car)
  ... 
  ...
```

Things are fine in this way. But, if I want the feature that when user click the edit link, there is a **popup window** to show the 'edit.html.haml' page, how to implement? I mean how to popup the edit page instead of load the edit page?

(**I am using Rails 3** which has deprecated the `:popup` option of `link_to`)

Comment: Do you actually need it to appear in separate window? You could always 'fake' a popup using css.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is open the form in a new window, you can set the link's target to "_blank":

```
%td
  =link_to(t("car.edit"), edit_car_path(car), :target => "_blank")
```